# Word for "drawing a decisive conclusion about a phenomenon according to specific personal experience"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for "drawing a decisive conclusion about a phenomenon according to specific personal experience"?

I often encounter people who can follow a pattern like that in an argument:

> A: What do you think about the new X cell phone?
>
> B: My sister bought one, and she could not operate it, so it's not
>   user friendly.

It's not only generalization, but also taking a case that you are familiar with and making conclusions about a certain object according to that case even if the conclusion is not relevant or connected.

Comment: I think you need to explain your thinking a bit more. In this context, I assume *user friendly* means "easy to operate". Unless B's sister is known to be exceptionally incompetent when dealing with modern technology, the fact that *she* couldn't operate the new phone is obviously "relevant/connected". The important point is that she's *only one person*, so maybe there's some other (unspecified) reason why her experience isn't a reliable guide to what others might think.

Comment: Closely related: [What's the name of the fallacy of using localised examples to suggest a {global} problem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396588/whats-the-name-of-the-fallacy-for-using-localised-examples-to-suggest-a-syst/396591#396591)

Answer (score 5):

The word you are looking for is ***anecdotal***.

> **Anecdotal (adj):** (of an account) not necessarily true or reliable, because based on personal accounts rather than facts or research.
>
> Example: Historic accounts of this era give no indication of any negative impact to fish populations and in fact, anecdotal accounts reflect quite the opposite.

[[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/anecdotal)

Comment: Your answer would be improved by including the source of your quoted definition.

Answer (score 2):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization) calls it *Hasty generalization*, but if I were A in OP's example I'd say...

> [You can't generalise from the particular.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you%20can%27t%20generalise%20from%20the%20particular%22&oq=%22you%20can%27t%20generalise%20from%20the%20particular%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.13975&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I don't understand why OP says his example is *"not only generalization"*, since that's precisely (and ***only***) what it is. Which arguably makes the question itself pointless, but I'm posting this answer because future visitors might find it after searching for words in the question title.

Comment: +1 On the baseball site I frequent the catchphrase is *SSS*, for Small Sample Size, employed to condemn evaluating a player based on his first few weeks in the majors.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, I don't know exactly how common it is across the world at large, but ["based on a sample size of one"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22based+on+a+sample+size+of+one%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is far from unknown in my neck of the woods. I notice several biology/human origins/SETI contexts in that link - they're certainly typical contexts where I use/encounter it.

Comment: _Hasty generalization_ was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: @J.R.: Personally, I don't normally even bother with the "hasty" bit. I tend to use words like "universalise/generic" when I have *positive* connotations in mind. Leaving "generalise" to be almost exclusively a *negative* term - not that there's really any scope for confusion if I say *"You can't generalise"*, or *"You're just generalising"*. It ain't never a good thing to me.

Comment: Your bias against generalizing is shortsighted, I think. We do that all the time. Without generalizations, We'd need to take the time to analyze & reanalyze the same or similar conditions over & over & then arrive at the same inferences over & over. If you see a cobra bite a man who then dies, you immediately generalize that cobras are dangerous & you infer that you must avoid them: next time you see a cobra, you'll avoid it: evolutionary survival value. _Overgeneralization_ is a different thing, but "first impressions are lasting impressions": that's human nature.

Comment: @StoneyB: SSS is universally condemned in statistical analysis because statistical power comes, **in part**, from a sufficiently large sample, which reduces the possibility that the data are merely flukes. If you flip a coin twice & it comes up heads, what can you conclude about coin flipping? Nothing. Flip it a million times, and the chances are significantly better that half will be heads & half tails. However, that's got nil to do with how athletes should be rated: some are flashes in the pan & others are finally consistent, even if their debut performances are spectacularly good or bad.

Comment: @Bill: You're being somewhat literal-minded there. My bias (as I thought I'd laboriously explained in that comment) is against the *word* being used indiscriminately for both positive and negative contexts. Obviously I have much the same cognitive faculties as all human beings. Well, if I'm honest, I truly believe I have more ability than most to revise my opinions as more evidence becomes available, but that's not really the point.

Comment: ...and the coin-flipping is a *terrible* example. If you point a gun at two people one after the other, pulling the trigger each time, what do you conclude about the dangers of playing with guns? More accurately, if an alien *you've never seen before* suddenly appears and eats two of your friends, what do you conclude about its intentions? Examples where you already know a lot about the situation aren't really relevant to what we're talking about here.

Comment: @BillFranke  "I think Kozma's our starter. .952 OPS!" "SSS, dude; that's in 79 plate appearances. Talk to me when he's got 600 under his belt."

Comment: @S: Yes, the second guy's looking for consistency.  Reproducibility is perhaps possible (not necessarily probable, though) with two study populations of 10,000 patients, but not with two athletes or even 100 athletes who start out with the same stats in their first 79 at-bats: each is a sample of only 1. Take 1000 players after 1000 at-bats, & you can generally predict how many will consistently have a high or a low OPS, but you can't tell about any one specific player.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I thought "Hasty generalization" was the formal name of a logical fallacy, much like _Post hoc ergo propter hoc_, _Argumentum ad populum_,  or _Poisoning the well_.  Inclusion of the word _hasty_ implies that the generalization occurs as part of a logical [fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies), as opposed to simple generalization. I think you _can_ generalize without committing a fallacy, such as _I don't like rainy days_, which might be generally true, albeit with exceptions (such as on the day after I happened to plant five new trees in my yard).

Comment: @J.R.: Apparently it can [also be called](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_accident) the *fallacy of **converse accident, reverse accident, destroying the exception,** or **a dicto secundum quid ad dictum simpliciter***. I've no idea which if any of those terms are considered "standard" by students of formal logic. But there's a difference between the kind of generalisation involved in saying *"I don't like Mondays"* (because *on average I don't*, over a lifetime) and *"I don't like people from Timbuktu"* (because I didn't like the only one I ever met).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Exactly – and I think your latter example is a classic _hasty generalization_, although I don't claim to be an expert in logical fallacies (my initial introduction to the subject came from Shulman's _Love is a Fallacy_: "Cool was I and logical" – LOL).

Answer (score 0):

"**Hearsay**", besides the legal definition, describes the scenario you described:

> 1. Unverified information heard or received from another; rumor.
> 2. Law Evidence based on the reports of others rather than the personal knowledge of a witness and therefore generally not admissible
>      as testimony.

From the freedictionary.com

Comment: I don't think this is right. Outside the legal context, *hearsay* wouldn't normally be used in respect of the *known, uncontested* evidence/experience of a speaker's ***sister***. It's invariably used in respect of things said by *unknown/unspecified people*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe it's just me but if someone said to me what OP used for her example, I would say "that's just hearsay! I can't go by that!"

Comment: Okay, so you're A in the example. If I were B, I might reply *"No it's not! Phone her up if you don't believe me!"* Would my case be weakened if she failed to answer the phone? (she can't work it, don't forget! :) Seriously, I think dismissing evidence from the **sister** of someone you're actually speaking to as "hearsay" sounds at the very least provocative. What if it was B's wife? Or even B himself? You have to believe some of the people some of the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I see your point.  I guess I would still want to question any anecdotal statement.  I probably would call the source to turn hearsay to something more verifiable.  Lol!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the *[post hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)* fallacy: basing a conclusion on a single instance. It doesn't matter whether it's true (it's true that the woman in the OP's example sentence found it not user-friendly), false ([Reagan's "welfare queen"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_queen)), or merely hearsay. A single instance of event A followed by event B doesn't prove anything: it merely illustrates a correlation or coincidence.

It's also called ["the fallacy of anecdotal evidence"](http://courses.csusm.edu/fallacies/anecdotal.htm) and ["the cherry picking fallacy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking_%28fallacy%29).

Comment: Post hoc &tc is something different: A happened, then B happened, so A is the cause of B. There's only an A in OP's example, no B. But your others are spot on: a conclusion based on insufficient or unanalyzed evidence, and a conclusion based on improperly selected evidence.

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree. [1] A: She tried to operate it. B: She failed. Conclusion: It's not user friendly. Okay, being user friendly or unfriendly's not an event but a state. Wikipedia says post hoc's also "referred to as _false cause, coincidental correlation, or correlation not causation_", **similar**, not the same; [2] A: The pitcher touched his cap & balls. B: The batter struck out. Conclusion: This pitcher can strike out a batter if he touches his cap & balls before he throws a pitch. The claim that it's not user friendly's based on a 1-case coincidence: false cause. Logic's hard!

Comment: The fallacy "after this, therefore because of this" is fine in 2] but would apply in 1] only if the brother somehow concluded that his sister's failure was caused by her attempt (in your example) or by her purchase (in the original). "The iPhone's a good device, if I'd given it to her and shown her how to use it would have worked just fine, but June screws up everything she buys and tries to work out for herself." Of course in that particular case *post hoc* might (coincidentally) be true.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thank you for that. It clears things up. :-)

Comment: I didn't know that *cherry-picking* had been elevated to the status of a "fallacy". It sounds a bit weird to me, since it's so strongly associated with *deliberately falsifying statistics/attempting to mislead*, rather than (possibly accidentally) falling victim to an error of logic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That categorization comes from Wikipedia & may be too strong. Regardless, it is specious reasoning to choose only examples that support one's own POV rather than present a realistic picture of the range of evidence. It's not **necessarily** _falsifying statistics_ to present a half-truth. It's more like saying _There's no better aspirin than XYZ Aspirin_; although this may be true, it omits the information that all chemically equivalent aspirins are equally effective.

Comment: @Bill: Well, I must say that it would never occur to me to describe  XYZ Aspirin's trade puff as "cherry-picking". But arguably if it turns out they only got to [Eight out of ten cats prefer Whiskas](http://www.lawdit.co.uk/reading_room/room/view_article.asp?name=../articles/Whiskas.htm) by starting with 1000 cats, and eliminating 990 of the ones that *didn't* prefer it from the trial, that would qualify. But in that case I'd be more interested in what they preferred it **to** (dogfood, perhaps? :)

Comment: @F: I used it as an example of _specious reasoning_ and _a half-truth_, not of _cherry picking_.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word but the phrase I think you're searching for is a "base of reference".  A base of reference is what we compare all incoming information to, and without it we are unable to conceive.

Example: If you were to explain to someone who was born blind what light is like they could have a base of reference from their other senses to understand that this sense would be different. However, that person does not have a base of reference for color you couldn't explain what color is and have them conceive of it. You couldn't even convince them that it was real.

Answer (score 0):

You example is one of **subjectivism**, n.

OED

> **1.** *Chiefly depreciative*. **The practice of giving priority to or laying emphasis on subjective consciousness, personal experience, etc.; any of various methods based on or advocating this. Hence also: lack of objectivity, bias.**
>
> 1900   Pilot 23 June 515/1   *This would..eliminate the danger of subjectivism, and secure that the points emphasized should not be merely personal or of local..importance.*
>
> 1989   M. A. Notturno Perspectives on Psychologism 172   *The subjectivism of regarding what the subject ‘knows’ as being justified by the subject's private experiences.*
>
> 2009   P. B. Ebrey et al. East Asia v. xxv. 439   *People learned to interpret any deviation from Mao's line as defects in their thinking due to their subjectivism and liberalism.*

However, we would usually use the adjective:

That argument is **subjective**.

Answer (score 0):

A bit peculiar and requiring coining, but perhaps “first-impressionism” or “first-impressionist” could serve as an adequate term, in reference to the common practice of drawing sweeping conclusions based on first impressions of phenomena.